# How can I add Property to my android app through which i can set the Service URL from the settings menu

Tags: android, xamarin, properties

My android app will connect to the service url which pass the data and the data will be saved in my App data-variables and the working will start .So,I want the user to dynamically change the service url from the Settings menu if needed. If not then the default url must do its work.
I have declared a variable in Resources/values/strings.xml file. But this is Static I want to make it dynamic.
and the url must be set before the application starts 
I'm Working in Visual Studio 2017 With Xamarin Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So,I want the user to dynamically change the service url from the Settings menu if needed. If not then the default url must do its work.

You can use [Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs) to achieve that:

Example:

1. Create a `preferences.xml` in `Resouces\xml` to hold the settings:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <PreferenceScreen 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <EditTextPreference
         android:key="pref_url"
         android:title="pref_url"
         android:summary="This is service url"
         //default value for url service setting
         android:defaultValue="http://www.google.com" />
   </PreferenceScreen>
   ```
2. Create a `SettingsFragment` and `SettingsActivity` as container of the setting:

   ```
   public class SettingsFragment:PreferenceFragment
   {
       public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
           AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.Preferences);
       }

       public override void OnResume()
       {
           base.OnResume();
           PreferenceScreen.SharedPreferences.RegisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
       }

       public override void OnPause()
       {
           base.OnPause();
       PreferenceScreen.SharedPreferences.UnregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
       }
   }

   [Activity(Label = "PreferenceDemo")]
   public class SettingsActivity:Activity
   {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
           SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Settings);
           FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.container, new SettingsFragment()).Commit();

       }
   }
   ```
3. Get the setting from anywhere in your app:

   ```
   ISharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   string syncConnPref = sharedPref.GetString("pref_url", "");
   ```

Here is the complete Demo:[PreferenceDemo](https://github.com/elvisxia/PreferenceDemo).

Comment: `Resource.id.container` is the LinearLayout of `Resource.Layout.SettingsActivity`. I've added the link to the complete demo, please have a try.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'PreferenceDemo.SettingsFragment' to 'Android.Content.ISharedPreferencesOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener' PreferenceDemo E:\PreferenceDemo-master\PreferenceDemo-master\PreferenceDemo\SettingsFragment.cs 28 Active
Here is the error I got when i tried your PreferenceDemo in my VS2017

Comment: Please remove the `OnResume` and `OnPause` and the codes inside, in file `SettingsFragment.cs` ,They are unrelated codes.

Comment: Yes,I did the same!